# what is the meaning of while here?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

what does this mean?

> While not industrial grade, these implementations are easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

This is usage 2.1 in the [Oxford English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/while):

> **while**, conjunction. In spite of the fact that; although.
>
> ‘while I wouldn't recommend a night-time visit, by day the area is full of interest’

Alternative phrasings for your sentence:

> Although [they are] not industrial grade, these implementations are easy to follow.
>
> These implementations, though [they are] not industrial grade, are easy to follow.